# Python Issue with Values

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in python (just learning as it looks a nice language) but have come across a small problem.

My code works for the most part but decided to print found process rather than just the first found process. All i want it to print out is whether it has found a process or not.

I have searched for sshd for example and my output has been

```
found
found
found
```

as there are 3 processes running.

my code is

```
import os
import signal

vProcessName = "sshd"

for line in os.popen("ps xa"):
    fields = line.split() 
    if vProcessName  in fields[4]: 
        print("Found")
```

Thank you for any help you may provide its greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is the question? Why doesn't it leave the cycle after first finding? How about `break`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`break` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement), you can get out of the loop:

```
for line in os.popen("ps xa"):
    fields = line.split()

    if vProcessName  in fields[4]:
        print("Found")
        break # <----
```

Alternativing using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(vProcessName in line.split() for line in os.popen("ps xa")):
    print("Found")
```